# RxCallAdapter in Retrofit error

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am making an API call using retrofit, and I am using the RxJavaCallAdapter. Now when the API call returns, both the onNext and onError is called, which I know because I have log messages inside both callbacks. This happens only occasionally. So, anyone could point out what the reason may be.

Comment: please post a sample code.

Comment: What do the errors say?